# Casting from int to long throws exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 2 columns (string & int).  The current value for the int column is `-1`.

Using a `SQLDataReader` I'm reading rows from this table:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name;
    public long Number;
}

using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject()
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        o.Name= dataReader.GetString(0);
        o.Number = dataReader.GetInt64(1);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` when reading the `Number` column. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the type of your second column in db? And what is it's value?

Comment: Could you please enter more information: like the schema for the table and the command that you are executing?

Comment: Can you post the exception ? It might have more information.

Comment: Could be, that the index "1" is not pointing to the right column. Could be, that the column's type is not Int64. Could be, that the value inside the second column is not castable. Could be, that there is no value (NULL)...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth what You are saying makes no sense - where do you have object ? GetInt64 returns int not an object

Comment: @MajkeloDev I haven't seen the code of the reader, but internally I suspect it pulls out objects as you can do a straight `GetValue`, which returns just an object of the cell value. I would suspect the methods just then cast this to the target data type, which then enacts the runtime check I eluded to. That said, without checking the impl I can't be certain of that.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to: int parsedInt; o.Name = int.TryParse(dataReader["fieldName"].ToString(), out parsedInt) ? parsedInt: (int?)null; - On the assumption your sql field allows nulls.

Comment: @Ivan Also, you don't need to worry about doing anything extra to get an `Int32` into an `Int64`, that cast can happen implicitly. Call `GetInt32` instead, which is what the underlying value is (as you state).

Comment: @MajkeloDev Sorry, I deleted my original comment because it was a little vague. The issue is with the unboxing not allowing you to unbox to something other than the original type. I've amended my answer and undeleted it with this explanation, and show the reader code attempting to do this when the data type is not actually `Int64`.

Comment: It pulls out the native type and if you use `GetInt64` no boxing/unboxing is involved. [`TryReadSqlValueInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,6d2a05f1dd1477e3,references) will use the provided metadata to determine the type to initialize the correct property(f.e. `Storage.Int64`) This property is returned from `SqlDataReader.GetInt64` whereas the indexer returns the boxed object.

Comment: @TimSchmelter From what I could see, un-boxing is the fallback because the native type isn't an `Int64` in this instance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter From what I could see in the code it winds a path to an attempted unboxing from the internal `Value` object, causing this exception, but I'm only reading the code so that may not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to make correct conclusion. Your columns DataType is int not bigint so You can't call it via .GetInt64(), because it's being unboxed and

> You can't unbox Int32 -> Int64

As @Adam Houldsworth mentioned -

> "Read what is given, not what You want"

To resolve Your problem just switch GetInt64() to GetInt32(). See below:

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject()
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        o.Name= dataReader.GetString(0);
        o.Number = dataReader.GetInt32(1); // safe implicitly cast no need to make it manually
    }
}
```

If You don't know exact underlying DataType You can always do it other way. Please see code below:

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject()
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        o.Name = dataReader.GetString(0);
        var number = dataReader.GetValue(1);

        try
        {
            o.Number = Convert.ToInt64(number);
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException)
        {
            Throw new Exception("Underlying DataType is not convertable to int 64.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The remarks section of [SqlDataReader.GetInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64(v=vs.90).aspx) states:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a 64-bit signed integer.

By the way: don't forget to call IsDBNUll if your value is nullable

Are you sure that the retrieved data is a **bigint** in your database? if it is an int, or a nchar / nvarchar, you should use the corresponding function and cast or parse it to a System.Int64

**Some advises to improve robustness of your code**

- use SqlDataReader[columnName] instead of GetInt64. This will give you the object in the original type, which is most likely to be convertible to your long.
- Using column names instead of column numbers increases the stability of your code. It will still work if columns are reordered in your query, or if a different column is added or removed from the query
- If you really want to stick to the GetInt... functions, use SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(column name) to get your column number.
- Before assigning use SqlDataReader.GetFieldType to check the type of the column and use the corresponding GetInt.. function

Comment: True - I suggest OP to try with GetInt32 and see what happens

Comment: @MajkeloDev It will work as the value is a 32-bit integer in reality. All this is moot anyway because an `int` can implicitly be a `long` with no explicit casting.

Comment: MajkeloDev: true about the int casting to a long. But inside the database the int is not really an int in the sense of being a four byte piece of contiguous memory. SqlDataReader.GetInt32 is meant to convert the database representation of the int, which officially is hidden into a System.Int32, which can implicitly be cast to a System.Int64

Comment: _"Are you sure that the retrieved data is a bigint in your database?"_ OP already stated: _"The current value for the **int** column is -1"_ +1

Comment: @HaraldDutch You're definitely right. Int32 can be implicitly casted to Int64 but as Adam Houldsworth mention - GetInt64() method is trying to unbox the value and it will throw an InvalidCastException because Int32 cannot be unboxed to Int64 even though it can be implicitly casted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read it as an `int` via `GetInt32`. You don't need to cast it to `long` because that can be done implicitly with safety by the runtime.

The runtime won't let you un-box from `object` to another data-type without first un-boxing `object` to the correct internal data type of whatever the `object` is, then casting to the next one. This quirk isn't anything to do with data readers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 1;

    object o = i;

    long l = (long)o; // invalid cast, trying to unbox to something other than the original type

    l = (long)(int)o; // No invalid cast, un-boxed to int then cast to long.
}
```

Specifically with `SqlDataReader`, because your underlying type is not `Int64`, it internally tries to un-box directly to the wrong type:

```
internal Int64 Int64 {
    get {
        ThrowIfNull();

        if (StorageType.Int64 == _type) {
            return _value._int64;
        }
        return (Int64)this.Value; // anything else we haven't thought of goes through boxing.
    }
    // set excluded for brevity
}
```

Taken from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBuffer.cs,1b180f5ee49fc7ee

TL;DR; Do what the documentation says (as advised by HaraldDutch's answer) and read the correct expected type.

Comment: Now I get your point and agree with You - it's OP fault that he is trying to call GetInt64() method while the underlying DataType is different.(most probably). GetInt64() Method is trying to unbox the value internally and bah - exception.

Comment: @MajkeloDev Yeah, I didn't explain myself very well first time around because I used to get stung by this years ago and now by default I don't attempt to do this, I always read what is given, not what I want. The problem with the engrained behaviour is that I can't very easily explain the *why* any more :-)

Comment: I think that question can bo closed with following conclusion "Read what is given, not what You want" :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value you are trying to get is bigint in database.
BIGINT is the equivalent of Int64 (which is long in C#).If its other than bigint try using Convert.ToInt64()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unbox SQLDataReader object from (object{int}) to long, you should  know, what there is no direct way. For example this code

```
long _result = (long)(sqlDR["IntTypeField"] ?? 0L);
```

will generate "System.InvalidCastException". 
You should use more comprehensive function, like this

```
public static T NvlO<T>(object a, T b)
{
    if (a == null)
        return b;
    else
    {
        var lSrcType = a.GetType();
        var lDestType = typeof(T);

        if (lDestType.IsValueType && lDestType.IsAssignableFrom(lSrcType))
            return (T)a;
        var lDestTC = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        if (lDestTC.CanConvertFrom(lSrcType))
            return (T)lDestTC.ConvertFrom(a);
        else
        {
            var lSrcTC = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(lSrcType);
            String lTmp = lSrcTC.ConvertToInvariantString(a);
            return (T)lDestTC.ConvertFromInvariantString(lTmp);
        }
    }
}
```